# Getting password information for all users in Active Directory

Tags: .net, active-directory

I've been asked to write a program that checks how long until a password expires for ALL users in our AD.  The program then sends out an email to those users who's password is expiring in 3 days or less.  The email part is easy, but I'm not too familiar with AD, nor have I been able to find anything useful out there on the internet.

For a more concrete explanation, if I had a database with a table called users, I would do something like this with SQL:

```
 SELECT FirstName, LastName, PasswordLastChangedDate, PasswordExpireDate
 FROM users;
```

I need to do this with VB (or C#).  I've poked around in the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace, but haven't had any luck.  Can anyone point me in the proper direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5][1] which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching.

That "query-by-example" user can also have some "advanced" search options set, stuff like
when a password will expire and so on:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
// which has a password that will expire in 3 days or less
UserPrincipal userTemplate = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
userTemplate.AdvancedSearchFilter.AccountExpirationDate(DateTime.Today.AddDays(3), MatchType.LessThanOrEquals);

// instantiate searcher
PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(userTemplate);

// enumerate matching users
foreach (Principal foundPrincipal in searcher.FindAll())
{
   UserPrincipal foundUser = (foundPrincipal as UserPrincipal);

   if (foundUser != null)
   {
       // do something with users found - e.g. send e-mail
   }
}
```

Comment: Dude, I love you.  I've been looking all morning for something like this.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Couple things - The sample is based on Account Expiry versus Password Expiry so you'll want to tweak that. Additionally, if you are using Fine Grained Password Policies in your environment, this is a much harder problem to solve as you'll need to ask each user object for it's effective policy and then calculate the password expiry date based on that.